# Button becomes invisible when recyclerview is filled with data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have such xml for RV item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/counter" />

    <de.applicatione.jobs.jobbSeek.adapters.LollipopFixedWebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
        android:labelFor="@id/webView"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/question" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/enter_your_answer_polls"
        android:background="@drawable/polls_field"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_answer_polls"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/webView" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/answers_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_input" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/question_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="20"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/answers_options">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="@string/previous_question_polls"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@drawable/main_screen_btn"
            android:text="@string/next_question_polls"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/prev_question"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my RV xml:

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/main_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:visibility="gone" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The problem is that I don't see my buttons from item xml. They become invisible when I fill RV with some data. I checked everything and can't understand how to fix this problem. I'm pretty sure that problem is with xml but I don't understand where it is. I used Layout inspector and I see that my buttons below RV in RV item, but I can't scroll and see them. Maybe I did any mistakes in xml? I thought that maybe problem is with fixed RV size or nested scrolling and added this code:

```
!answersList.hasFixedSize()
answersList.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your RecyclerView's height to be 0dp. This will force it to take the height of whatever constraints you give it. Also, your top-level ConstraintLayout's height should be `match_parent`. And I adjusted some constraints as well, and switched out your nested ConstraintLayout for a LinearLayout:

(I switched out/removed resources in my IDE that showed red, but the layout is the same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/counter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:labelFor="@id/webView"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/question" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="editText"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/webView" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/answers_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/question_buttons"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_input" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/question_buttons"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: but with your top/bottom constraints RV becomes invisible :(

Comment: Check my edit. This one is tested and working, although I can't vouch for what effect that `LollipopFixedWebView` will have. WebViews should normally have a height of `match_parent`. I just turned it into a TextView for now.

Comment: it still doesn't work :( maybe I did smth wrong in activity class, but on the other hand xml representation doesn't depend on activity actions